# Erro ao gerar um ruido em um arquivo de audio

Tags: python

estou criando um ruido para um arquivo para depois passar por um filtro, para fins de estudo mas estou com o seguinte erro:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2312604,2) (2312604,)

Meu codigo:

```
# Carregando o sinal de EEG
fs, data = wavfile.read('ll.wav')

# Adicionando ruído gaussiano ao sinal
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, len(data))
noisy_data = data + noise

# Criando o filtro passa-baixas
b, a = signal.butter(4, 5, 'high', fs=fs)

# Aplicando o filtro passa-baixas no sinal ruidoso
filtered_data = signal.filtfilt(b, a, noisy_data)

# Plotando o sinal ruidoso e o sinal filtrado
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.plot(noisy_data, label='Ruidoso')
plt.plot(filtered_data, label='Filtrado')
plt.xlabel('Tempo (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Se puderem me ajudar ficaria grato !

Comment: Nessa parte `noisy_data = data + noise`  esta somando arrays de tamanho diferentes, se notar no código.. justamente essa mensagem é um indicio **ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2312604,2) (2312604,)**  quando tentou fazer uma conta matemática entre dois arrays  de tamanhos diferentes .. **Broadcasting**  esse cara vai tentar fazer a conta  matemática   entre arrays. foi esse o aviso.  `noisy_data = data[:,0] + noise` assim sera selecionada uma coluna do array  **data** e somar com  **noise**

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certo aqui, porém o ruído está muito imperceptível, no plot, estou tentando aumentar mais estou conseguindo